# ESP32S3 ULP SENS_ register read or write not working

Tags: esp32

On ESP32S3 board I use C macros to program the ULP FSM processor.
Everything works as expected, only the following read and write REG
instructions seems not read or set the register: `SENS_SAR_PERI_CLK_GATE_CONF_REG`
If I read the register value to rtc_slow_debug1 variable before the set and to rtc_slow_debug2 after set, and I print it to serial, it is identical, nothing happens.
I know I can set this register on the main CPU by `rtc_gpio_init()` function, but I need to make it in the ULP code.

Any idea?
Thank you!

Snippet of the code:

```
const ulp_insn_t program[] =
{
  I_MOVI(R3,_v(rtc_slow_debug1)),
  I_RD_REG(SENS_SAR_PERI_CLK_GATE_CONF_REG,0,15), //it reads something, but not the desired the register
  I_STL(R0,R3,0),
  I_RD_REG(SENS_SAR_PERI_CLK_GATE_CONF_REG,16,31), //it reads something, but not the desired the register
  I_STH(R0,R3,0),
  I_WR_REG_BIT(SENS_SAR_PERI_CLK_GATE_CONF_REG,SENS_IOMUX_CLK_EN_S,1), //it does nothing...
  I_MOVI(R3,_v(rtc_slow_debug2)),
  I_RD_REG(SENS_SAR_PERI_CLK_GATE_CONF_REG,0,15), //check if write succeeded, but nothing changed
  I_STL(R0,R3,0),
  I_RD_REG(SENS_SAR_PERI_CLK_GATE_CONF_REG,16,31), //check if write succeeded, but nothing changed
  I_STH(R0,R3,0),
...
```

If I set or read the register on main CPU, it works.
Like:

```
rtc_gpio_init(GPIO_NUM_4); //works, sets the register
rtc_slow_debug4=READ_PERI_REG(SENS_SAR_PERI_CLK_GATE_CONF_REG); //works, reads the reg appropriately
```